# How can is sum up an input range of numbers?

Tags: python, sum, range

Dear stackoverflow community!

I just started learning python and want to figure out how to write following program:`

```
number = int(input('Enter ten numbers:'))
for i in range(1, 10):
  while True:
    try:
      number = int(input("Enter another number: "))
      break
    except:
      print("This is a string") 
for i in range(1, 10):
  res = 0
  res += int(input())
  print('The sum of these 10 numbers is:', res)
```

I want the user to input 10 numbers and during the process I want to check if the numbers are actually integers. So the number input works, it checks if its an integer, but then how can make this work at the same time? (To sum up the 10 integers that I got as input) :

```
for i in range(1, 10):
  res = 0
  res += int(input())
  print('The sum of these 10 numbers is:', res)
```

So basically i want two conditions for those 10 numbers that I got as Input.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to define `res = 0` *before* the loop

Comment: You only need to loop once, not twice. Are you sure you know what `input` does? You seem to treat it as a storage variable of some kind.

Comment: `range(1, 10)` are only 9 values, since the "end" argument is not inclusive. Also you overwrite the value of your single variable `number`, you don't store the numbers anywhere. You also don't handle the error when the first input is not a number, since it is outside of `try ... except`.

Comment: thanks for the input guys; I did know that looping twice doesnt work, I just wanted to visualize that I want to do 2 things with this loop basically x) @Chris_Rands; can you maybe elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply checking the user input, not storing it somewhere. Use this instead:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) != 10:
    try:
      numbers.append(int(input("Enter another number: ")))
    except ValueError:
      print("This is not an integer!") 

res = sum(numbers)
print('The sum of these 10 numbers is: {}'.format(res))
```

Comment: `sum` is of course the way to go, but you might point out the error in the OP's loop based summing.

Comment: oh yea, this approach with list makes way more sense. Thanks! I suppose I do know that I cant loop twice with for i in range(); however I did hope there's an easy solution how to add summing the parts to the "check if its an integer" loop.